# (Ill)Logical statement

Tags: bash, scripting

I am attempting to make a simple script to flip my computer screen. My first if statement executes perfectly, but after that, thought $istouch is "on", the elif statement block will not execute! I have tried running bash with the -u option with no failure and have tried switching the checks, nothing works.

```
#!/bin/bash
xsetwacom --set 16 touch False
istouch='xsetwacom --get 15 touch'
$istouch
if [ "$istouch"=="off" ]
then
    xrandr -o inverted
    xinput set-prop 13 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop 15 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop 16 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    xsetwacom --set 15 touch True

elif [ "$istouch"=="on" ]
then
    xrandr -o 0
    xinput set-prop 13 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop 15 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop 16 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    xsetwacom --set 15 touch False
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` statments aren't running the way that you think. You can turn up the debugging for Bash scripts like this by including the command `set -x` and subsequently turn it off with `set +x`.

#### Example

So we first add debugging like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

## DEBUG
set -x
xsetwacom --set 16 touch False
....
```

I then run your script, I called it `ex.bash`, so I invoke it:

```
$ ./ex.bash
```

Bash tries to execute this line:

```
if [ "$istouch"=="off" ]
```

And from the output, we can see that Bash is getting confused. It's running with the string `'xsetwacom --get 15 touch==off'`.

```
+ '[' 'xsetwacom --get 15 touch==off' ']'
```

The arguments to the `==` shouldn't be touching it like that. Bash is notoriously picky on things like this. So put some space before and after like this:

```
 if [ "$istouch" == "off" ]
 elif [ "$istouch" == "on" ]
```

So now this looks a bit better:

```
+ '[' 'xsetwacom --get 15 touch' == off ']'
+ '[' 'xsetwacom --get 15 touch' == on ']'
```

However you don't want to compare the stirng `$istouch`, you want to compare the results of the command that this string represents, so change the top of the script to this:

```
....
xsetwacom --set 16 touch False
istouch=$(xsetwacom --get 15 touch)
if [ "$istouch" == "off" ]
....
```

Now we're running the command `xsetwacom` and storing the results in `$istouch`. I do not have these devices so I get a message about `device 15`. But this is what the script does now:

```
++ xsetwacom --get 15 touch
+ istouch='Cannot find device '\''15'\''.'
+ '[' 'Cannot find device '\''15'\''.' == off ']'
+ '[' 'Cannot find device '\''15'\''.' == on ']'
```

Hopefully this gives you some insight into:

1. How to debug your script
2. Better understanding of the Bash syntax

#### More indepth look at the if statements

You might be left wondering why the `if` statement even matched at all. The problem is that if you give the `[` command a single string, it will treat this as a truth if the string is not empty, and the if statement will fall into its `then` section.

#### Example

```
$ [ "no"=="yes" ] && echo "they match"
they match

$ [ "notheydont"=="yes" ] && echo "they match"
they match
```

It may appear that there is a equality check occurring here, but there is not. `[ some-string ]` is short for `[ -n some-string ]`, that is a test for *some-string* being [n]on-empty. Using `set -x` shows us this:

```
$ set -x; [ "notheydont"=="yes" ] && echo "they match"; set +x
+ '[' notheydont==yes ']'
+ echo 'they match'
they match
+ set +x
```

If we put some space between the arguments to the equality check:

```
# fails
$ set -x; [ "notheydont" == "yes" ] && echo "they match"; set +x
+ '[' notheydont == yes ']'
+ set +x

# passes
$ set -x; [ "yes" == "yes" ] && echo "they match"; set +x
+ set -x
+ '[' yes == yes ']'
+ echo 'they match'
they match
+ set +x
```

It now works as expected!

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much, it helps me a lot to know about the -x feature. However, one thing I don't understand is that in my version of the script it would (properly) flip the screen into tablet mode whenever I run it the first time. Why did the "$istouch"=="off" result to True?

Comment: @Timidger See updates.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for the corrections!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
istouch='xsetwacom --get 15 touch'
$istouch
```

with (note the back-quotes):

```
istouch=`xsetwacom --get 15 touch`
```